# PyQT5 Button Click to remove a label based on boolean values

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

What I'm trying to do is based on the idea that "if a button was clicked" the "display area" of my little app it'll draw additional labels buttons check buttons, and remove these based on if other buttons are pushed. The issue is that this will show my new label but it wont remove it, it'll actually make the text darker.

So...

`if button1 == True:` show the additional widgets
`else:` hide these additional widgets

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'test app'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 400
        self.statusBarMessage = "Status Bar Test"
        self.currentSprite = 'test.png'
        self.btn1Active = False
        self.btn2Active = False
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.statusBarMessage)

        # Set up the buttons
        btn1 = QPushButton('Set Up', self)
        btn1.setToolTip('Click me for an initial setup')
        btn1.resize(100,100)
        btn1.move(0,0)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)

        btn2 = QPushButton('Set Up', self)
        btn2.setToolTip('Click me for an initial setup')
        btn2.resize(100,100)
        btn2.move(100,0)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_clicked)

        spriteHelper = QLabel(self)
        spriteHelper.move(600,100)
        spriteHelper.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.currentSprite))
        spriteHelper.resize(200,280)

        #Display the area
        self.show()
        # I've tried moving this around in different areas without any luck
        self.testLabel = QLabel(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def btn1_clicked(self):
        print("Button 1 is clicked")
        self.btn1Active = True
        self.btn2Active = False
        self.currentSprite = 'win_blank_frown.png'
        print(self.btn1Active)
        self.statusBarMessage = "Button 1 was clicked"
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.statusBarMessage)
        print(self.btn2Active)

        # If the button was clicked and the boolean is true 
        # then create the label
        if self.btn1Active == True:
            self.testLabel.move(400,200)
            self.testLabel.setText("This is text")
            self.testLabel.show()
        # Else if an other button was pushed, set btn1Active to false
        # and remove the label from the main window
        else:
            layout.removeWidget(self.testLabel)
            self.testLabel.deleteLater()
            self.testLabel = None

    def btn2_clicked(self):
        print("Button 2 is clicked")
        self.btn2Active = True
        self.btn1Active = False
        self.currentSprite = 'test.png'
        self.statusBarMessage = "Button 2 was clicked"
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.statusBarMessage)
        print(self.btn2Active)
        print(self.btn1Active)
```

Comment: I suppose there is a logical mistake in your code. You set `self.btn1Active = True` in the `def btn1_clicked(self):` method and then you check `if self.btn1Active == True:`. Of course, it will always be `True`

Comment: By the way there is no need to write `if something == True:`. You can just write `if something:`.

Comment: I get that, but I don't understand that for example if button 2 is pushed it sets button1 to false, why does the label remain. Is there a update window function I'm not seeing?

Comment: Your code for removing the label will never be executed. There are no actions for removing it in the `btn2_clicked`. As far as I can see the only code that can remove the label is "dead" branch of the `if` statement.

Comment: Ohhhh okay so it'll never be false when the button is clicked, but in the other button theres a chance for that if too trigger. Damn I'm dumb let me try that.

Comment: Also I suppose the good idea is to invoke `testLabel.show()` and `testLabel.hide()` methods instead of bloodthirsty removing the label )

Comment: I just tried that with the hide and show. This will make my code so much easier to read now, I can potentially get rid of all the boolean functions now too. Thank you so much! Is there a way to bind abunch of widget into groupings that I can turn on and off? (New to GUI programming.)